# Where to place custom js for gmaps4rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I am using gmaps4rails gem, and when I want to create the Infobox, I have a JS like this:

```
Gmaps.map.infobox = function(boxText) {
  return {
     content: boxText
    ,disableAutoPan: false
    ,maxWidth: 0
    ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-145, 0)
    ,zIndex: null
    ,boxStyle: {
      background: "url(/assets/content/tipbox.gif) no-repeat"
      ,opacity: 0.90
      ,width: "280px"
       }
    ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
    ,closeBoxURL: "assets/content/close.gif"
    ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
    ,isHidden: false
    ,pane: "floatPane"
    ,enableEventPropagation: false
 }};
```

In order to add this js in my source, I render it right after I do:

```
<%= yield :scripts %>
```

But my question is: Is there any other better way of doing this and avoid opening two script tags?

Comment: you could include this kind of defaults within the gem's js.

Comment: Do you mean in gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js.coffee file?